# How to get around 'rmdir invalid option -r' error?

Tags: linux, terminal, elementaryos

I'm trying to remove a directory labeled 'phoneBackup' but it's not empty, it contains several dozen image files (.jpg, .gif, etc). I'm running the command "rmdir -r phoneBackup" from the parent directory, but upon execution I get the following error:

rmdir: invalid option -- 'r'
Try `rmdir --help' for more information.

Both the 'rmdir --help' and the 'man rmdir' commands don't show -r as an option. Is there a package I need to install, or is there some other way of removing the directory I can use in place of rmdir? I'm running Elementary OS Luna, which is built off of Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

rmdir work on empty directories. to remove directory and files/directories inside use

```
rm -rf /path/to/directory
```

Comment: Be extremely careful with this command, issuing a `rm -rf /` will wipe out the entire linux installation

Comment: That worked! thanks. But why does rm -rf work, but rm -r doesn't? Also, what do both the r and f stand for? Last question, why aren't they showing in the man pages?

Comment: r come for recursively, f come from force. and its good to use them together to remove also open files (from other applications)

Comment: Alright, but why is r an invalid option when stand-alone, but it executes just fine paired with f? I didn't have any applications causing any of the files to be opened.

Comment: As far as i understand -r give you an error when use with rmdir. When use with rm its another story. As I remember correctly Ubuntu make some changes in rm to avoid "suicide" rm -rf / so you can set to prompt you per file/directory or set explicitly force (do not ask questions, just do it)

Comment: -r is recursive as previously mentioned, however recursive only works if the directory is empty. It has nothing to do with 'Open files' as mentioned by @RomeoNinov. -f tells it to remove, even if the directory isn't empty.
rmdir doesn't have a -r option, so that is invaid.

Answer (score -3):

another way to delete directory and its subdirectory/file is using **WinSCP**, instead of using   `rm -rf /`    which probably wipe out the entire linux installation.

Comment: That's a really weird way of doing things...

Comment: Which is you don't run it with just a slash. In addition various distributions have checks in place to ask for confirmation in that case.